# List Sophie Germain primes

Tags: code-challenge, primes

## The Question

A *[Sophie Germain prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime)* is a prime \$p\$ such that \$2p+1\$ is prime as well. For example, 11 is a Sophie Germain prime because 23 is prime as well. Write the shortest program to calculate Sophie Germain primes in ascending order

## Rules

- The Sophie Germain primes must be generated by **your** program, not from an external source.
- Your program **must** calculate all Sophie Germain primes under \$2^{32}-1\$
- You must print each distinct Sophie Germain prime your program finds.
- The person with the lowest score wins

## Scoring

- 2 points per byte of your code
- -10 if you can show a prime generated by your program greater than \$2^{32}-1\$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23675/discussion-on-question-by-user3502615-list-sophie-germain-primes).

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 19 bytes * 2 - 10 = 28

Note that the online compiler/executor doesn't show output because it's an infinite loop.

```
K1#~K1I&!tPK!tPhyKK
```

Explained:

```
K1                      K=1
  #                     While true:
   ~K1                  K+=1
      I                 If
       &                logical AND
        !tPK            K is prime
            !tPhyK      2*K+1 is prime (y is double, h is +1)
                  K     Print K
```

Comment: `PZ` doesn't return a truthy or falsy value. It returns the prime factorization of `Z`. Testing for prime is `!tPZ`, which checks if the prime factorization only contains one factor.

Comment: Yes. Now it works. `!tP` mistakes `0` and `1` to be prime though, since their prime factorization only contains 1 factor. Easy fix is to replace all `Z` by `K` and assign `K2` at the beginning.

Comment: Some other golfs: assign `K1` instead of `K2`, and swap the if and the increment. This way you can remove the `)`. And `+1*K2` is the same thing as `hyK`.

Comment: Ah, I had just read about those on the tutorial page. Does it work for you on https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K2%23I%26!tPK!tPhyKK)~K1&debug=0

Comment: The online compiler doesn't show a result, because the program is stuck in an infinite loop. And the website shows only output, after the program finishes. I've tested the code using the offline compiler. It works.

Comment: Swapping if-condition-print and incrementing-K saves still 1 byte: `K1#~K1I&!tPK!tPhyKK`

Answer (score 4):

## CJam

For 17 chars we get full enumeration up to 2^32:

```
G8#,{_mp*2*)mp},`
```

For 4 chars more, we get a range just large enough to include an SG prime greater than 2^32:

```
G8#K_*+,{_mp*2*)mp},`
```

since 4294967681 = 2^32 + 385 < 2^32 + 400.

Of course, we could equally extend the range for free as

```
C9#,{_mp*2*)mp},`
```

Comment: This means you can submit it without the bonus for 17 characters or with the bonus for 21 characters

Comment: @user3502615, or with the bonus for 17 characters. Although it's debatable whether the SG prime I list was actually generated "by my program", since I don't have a powerful enough computer to run it that far.

Comment: `I,` treats `I` as a signed 32-bit integer, so the maximum value for `I` is `2 ** 31 - 1`.

Comment: @Dennis, is that a documented property of the language or an implementation quirk of the Java implementation?

Comment: It's not documented, but the behavior is consistent for both the Java and the online interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>16</s> <s>8</s> 7 * 2 - 10 = 4

*<s>-8</s> 12 thanks to @[Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)*

```
fȯṗ→Dİp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9odXNr///ihpE1MGbIr@G5l@KGkkTEsHD//w)

A list of all natural numbers that are Sophie Germain primes. I hope it's valid, because it doesn't terminate when you try to show the entire list, but Husk lazily evaluates it, so you can just take the required amount.

```
fȯṗ→Dİp
f         Filter
     İp   the prime numbers
    D     that, when doubled
   →      and incremented by 1
 ȯṗ       are prime
```

Another way to do it, also 7 bytes:

```
fṗm÷2İp
```

Comment: I had this exact same program, but it didn't display anything(like you have said), so I wrote an APL answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes, score = 4

*Thanks to @ovs for -1 byte!*

```
∞ʒx>‚pP
```

(Technically) Prints an infinite list of Sophie Germain primes! (Hence, score is subtracted by 10)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5Mq7B41zCoI@P8fAA)

### How?

```
∞ʒ        # For each natural number 'p'...
  x>‚     # Pair p with 2p + 1 (The ‚ is not a comma, it is a weird sort of quotation)
     p    # Are they both prime?
      P   # Then multiply the boolean values! (And implicitly print if the product is 1)
```

Comment: [`∞ʒx>‚pP`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5Mq7B41zCoI@P8fAA) for 7 bytes.

Comment: [`∞<Øʒ·>p`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8m8MzTk06tN2u4P9/AA) for an alternative 7-byter. Too bad `2` is truthy, otherwise the `<` could have been removed.

Comment: This is `‚ SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK`, not `, COMMA`. This can be really confusing, but the first pairs up two numbers while the latter prints to STDOUT

Comment: @ovs Just figured that out... :P

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 2 * 16 bytes - 10 = 22

Uses the customary method of prime checking in Pyth with the `!tP` and applies it both to the number and its safe-prime, with a little trick to check both at once. Goes up to `10^10`, so I'm going for the bonus.

```
f!+tPTtPhyTr2^TT
```

<strike>Explanation coming soon.</strike>

```
f          r2^TT     Filter from 2 till 10^10
 !                   Logical not to detect empty lists
  +                  List concatenation
   tP                All but the firs element of the prime factorization
    T                The filter element
   tP                All but the firs element of the prime factorization
    hyT              2n+1
```

[Try under 1000 online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f!%2BtPTtPhyTr2%5ET3).

Comment: This takes a machine with about 40 GB of RAM memory. Quite efficient ;-)

Comment: I don't think you can claim the - 10 unless you have actually successfully run the code?

Comment: @orlp no, I asked OP and he said making the range smaller and simulating the whole program would be sufficient: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21585393#21585393

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), `10 - ⍨ 2 × 27` = 44

```apl
f←{⎕←⍵⍴⍨⌽∧\1⍭⍵,1+2×⍵⋄∇⍵+1}1+⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qW9CjtgmGRhbmXEBOQACQY2zyPw1IVQP5QOpR79ZHvVse9a541LP3UcfyGMNHvWuBYjqG2kaHp4Mku1sedbQDGdqGtYbaj7oW/f@fpmAIAA)

Made with some golfing help and general APL help from dzaima.

### Explanation

```apl
{⎕←⍵⍴⍨⌽∧\1⍭⍵,1+2×⍵⋄∇⍵+1}1+⊢
                        1+⊢ add 1 to the input (initially, 1)
             1+2×⍵          double and increment it
         1⍭⍵,               prepend the primality check(1 or 0)
       ∧\                   and scan with LCM
   ⍵⍴⍨⌽                     reverse & reshape using self
                            (if test is falsy, then this results in ⍬)
 ⎕←                         and display it with newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes, score 2

```
Þp:d›↔
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnnA6ZOKAuuKGlCIsIiIsIiJd)

```
     ↔ # Union of...
Þp     # Primes
  :d›  # Primes * 2 + 1
```

-10 score because it prints an infinite list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes, score -2

```
Ƥ←½Q
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FiuOLXnUNuHQ3sAlxUnJxVBBmCQA)

```
Ƥ←½Q
Ƥ          Non-deterministically choose a prime number
 ←         Decrement
  ½        Divide by 2
   Q       Check if result is a prime
```

By default, Nekomata prints all possible results.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 34 (2 * 22 - 10)

```
C9#{ImpI2*)mp&{Ip}&}fI
```

Prints all Sophie Germain primes under `12 ** 9`, which includes `4294967681 > 2 ** 32`.

I estimate that this will take roughly 8 hours on my machine. I'll run it tonight.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>124</s> 123 bytes

```python
i=3
q=[2]
while 1:
 p=1
 for x in range(2,round(i**.5)+1):p=min(p,i%x)
 if p:
  q+=[i];s=(i-1)/2
  if s in q:print(s)
 i+=2
```

How does it work?

```python
i=3                                 # Start at 3
q=[2]                               # Create list with first prime (2), to be list of primes.
while 1:                            # Loop forever
 p=1                                # Set p to 1 (true)
 for x in range(2,round(i**0.5)+1): # Loop from 2 to the number's square root. x is the loop value
     p=min(p,i%x)                   # Set p to the min of itself and the modulo of
                                    # the number being tested and loop value (x).
                                    # If p is 0 at the end, a modulo was 0, so it isn't prime.
 if p:                              # Check if p is 0
  q+=[i]                            # Add the current number (we know is prime) to list of primes (q)
  s=(i-1)/2                         # Generate s, the number that you would double and add 1 to make a prime.

  if s in q:print(s)                # If (i-1)/2 is a prime (in the list), then that prime satifies
                                    # the condition 2p+1 is prime because i is 2p+1, and i is prime
 i+=2                               # Increment by 2 (no even numbers are prime, except 2)
```

Try it online [here](http://repl.it/n4F).

---

My computer says it is has generated 0.023283 % of all the Sophie Germain primes below 2^32.

When it's finished, I'll post it on pastebin if there are enough lines. You can use it to check you've got them all.

Comment: `.5` is shorter than `0.5`

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 2*54-10 = 98 <s>132</s>

```
i a=all((>0).rem a)[2..a-1]
p=[n|n<-[2..],i n,i$2*n+1]
```

`i` is a prime check. `p` takes all numbers `n` where both `n` and `2*x+1` are prime. `p` is an infinite list.

Edit: better way for checking if `2*n+1` is prime.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 2*49 - 10 = 88

```
p=primes(2^33)
print(p[map(n->isprime(2n+1),p)])
```

Prints them in list format, `[2,3,5,11,...]`. If that format, using the `primes` function, or waiting until all the computation is done to print isn't acceptable, this prints them one per line as it runs.

```
isprime=f
for i=1:2^33;f(i)&&f(2i+1)&&println(i)end
```

It's a little longer, 52 chars. Both compute all the Sophie Germain primes up to `2^33`, so they should get the 10 point discount.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 61*2 - 10 = 112

```
require'prime';Prime.each(1.0/0)do|n|p Prime.prime?(n*2+1)end
```

It would take forever to print out all values up to 2**32

## Edit

Shaved off a few bytes substituting Float::INFINITY for 1.0/0

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 2*57-10 = 104

```
use ntheory":all";forprimes{say if is_prime(2*$_+1)}2**33

2
3
5
11
...
8589934091
8589934271
```

42 seconds to 2^32, 1m26s to 2^33.  Will run 50% faster if `2*$_+1` is written as `1+$_<<1` but that's one more byte.

The module also installs `primes.pl` which has lots of filters including one for Sophie-Germain primes.  So: `primes.pl --so 2**33` (20 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

## PARI/GP, 46 * 2 - 10 = 82

```
forprime(p=2,2^33,if(isprime(2*p+1),print(p)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 2 * 64 bytes - 10 = 118

```python
n=1
while 1:n+=1;all((n-~n)*n%k for k in range(2,n))>0!=print(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8/WkKs8IzMnVcHQKk/b1tA6MSdHQyNPty5PUytPNVshLb9IIVshM0@hKDEvPVXDSCdPU9POQNG2oCgzr0QjT/P/fwA)

It turns out a normal prime test is shorter.

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 2 * 67 bytes - 10 = 124

```python
P=k=1
d=[]
while 1:P*=k*k;k+=1;P%k*k//2in d!=print(k//2);d+=P%k*[k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8A229aQK8U2OparPCMzJ1XB0CpAyzZbK9s6W9vW0DpAFcjU1zfKzFNIUbQtKMrMK9EA8TWtU7RtQZLR2bH//wMA)

This uses Wilson's theorem to generate a list of primes. When `k` is prime and `k//2` is prime as well (`in d`), this prints `k//2`.

This can be done a little more memory efficient by not collecting a list of primes but rather doing two prime tests at once at the cost of 4 bytes:

```python
P=k=1
m=3;R=4
while 1:P*=k*k;k+=1;R*=m*m*-~m*-~m;m+=2;P%k*R%m>0!=print(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8A229aQK9fW2DrI1oSrPCMzJ1XB0CpAyzZbK9s6W9vW0DpIyzZXK1dLtw6MrXO1bY2sA1SztYJUc@0MFG0LijLzSjSyNf//BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü♀σJàx╧☺▼∟╓X≥╣
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=810ce54a8578cf011f1cd658f2b9&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 85 bytes, score 170

```powershell
2
for($i=2){if((&($p={param($a)+!(2..($a-1)|?{!($a%$_)})})(++$i))*(&$p(2*$i+1))){$i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCsMgEAXQvbcI/MpMJIG4lx6lSFEykKDYRRdTz27lbV4t39Q@Z7qu7V1aGshBhze5NIIEzyqZyBJq0BpbvAmR3UJ@3@e2g39PXeYeeHGfyDkI80oWlfwKcQczK6T30Y2xyOMP)

A bit faster, but longer for [93 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcpBCsMgEEbhfW4R@CszGbJItsXDSFEqSVAM0oXM2Y10@76X08@X@@vPc/2k4juCbT2kQoh25xYDkSFk27Ir7iI4/mO121sEdR2h4RA7D3qhssqMQ5kGRuaFDDLtC6JszOOMql2nySD0Bw)

```powershell
for($i=2){if((&($p={param($a)for($u=1;++$u-$a){$k+=!($a%$u)}+!$k})(++$i))*(&$p(2*$i+1))){$i}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes => score 10

```
ȷ10ÆRḤ‘ẒƊƇ
```

Generates primes up to 10^10 > 2^32.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9qZWxsef//yLfDhlLhuKTigJjhupLGisaH//8) (TIO link is to a shorter version that generates only up to 1000, so it doesn't time out)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 11 bytes, score 12

```
9ᴇřᵽĐ2*⁺ṗ*ž
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f8uGW9qMzH27de2SCkdajxl0Pd07XOrrv//9oQx1jIDTUMYkFAA)

```
9ᴇřᵽ    generates the first 1,000,000,000 primes (there are 203,280,221 primes less than 2^32)
Đ2*⁺    calculates 2*p+1 for each prime
ṗ       is each 2*p+1 prime
*       multiply the two lists one element at a time
ž       remove all zeroes from list; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 20 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 16.46 bytes, score \$ \approx \$ 22.92

```
[xNx2*1+N&?xZK((x1+X
```

##### Explanation

```python
[                     # while True:
 xN                   #  x is prime?
   x2*1+N             #  x*2+1 is prime?
         &?           #  if both are true:
           xZK        #   print x
              ((      #  endif
                x1+X  #  x=x+1
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax), score 10

*2*10=20 score, -10 because it prints infinitely.*

```
▓i☼=ö│╪¥♠p
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b2690f3d94b3d89d0670&i=)

This is a PackedStax program, which unpacks to the following:

```
VIfc|psH^|pI
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=VIfc%7CpsH%5E%7CpI&i=)

## Explanation

```
  f         # filter from 1 to...
VI          # infinity by..
   |p       # is prime
          I # and
  c  sH^    # 2*p+1
        |p  # is prime
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-rprime`, 34 bytes, score 58

Prints infinitely and should be able to exceed `2**32` due to native support for large numbers, although I haven't bothered to actually wait around to check.

```ruby
Prime.each{p _1 if(2*_1+1).prime?}
```

[Attempt This Online! (with a timeout)](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnW0km5RQVFmbqpS7E2dotTC0syiVAX1EqBAfmmJOlcIhGFlBRXRMNAzMDDVVEjJX1pakqZrcVMpAKRZLzUxOaO6QCHeUCEzTcNIK95Q21BTD2yufS1E5eLUvBQIa8ECCA0A)